# Non-Zero function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that
$g(x)=0$ except at $c\in[a,b]$. Then $\int^{b}_{a}g(x)dx$ exists and further $\int^{b}_{a}g(x)dx=0$.

For this case, I have said: Let $\epsilon>0$ Let $a_0<a_1<a_2....<a_n$ be points such that

$max_i[a_i-a_{i-1}]$ $<$ $\frac{\epsilon}{2|g(c)|}$. Then clearly $L(g,D)=0$.
Considering $U(g,D)$, if $c$ is contained the partition, then it is contained in 2 subintervals of the partition, otherwise it is contained in only one. Hence, $U(g,D)\leq 2|g(c)|max[a_k-a_{k-1}]< \epsilon$
Hence $U(g,D)-L(g,D)=U(g,D)<\epsilon$
and so the integrand exists and is non-zero.

How do I prove it for the more general case when $g(x)$ is non-zero for $c_1,c_2....,c_k$ where each $c_i\in[a,b]$?

My attempt is:
For $c_1,c_2....,c_k$, we have that $U(g,D)\leq 2^kmax_i[{g(c_i)}]max_j[{a_j-a_{j-1}}]$ and we choose dissection to be such that $max_j[{a_j-a_{j-1}}]$ $<$ $\frac{\epsilon}{2^kmax_i[g(c_i)]}$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: For every partition, refine it by adding to it the points $c_1,...,c_k$ to it. The same argument that you used will work, except that you should use a bound involving the values of $g$ at all these points. For example $(|g(c_1)|+...+|g(c_k)|)\max(C_1,C_2,...,C_k)$, where $C_i$ are the lengths of the intervals of the partition that contain $c_1,...,c_k$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod thank you, may you please look at my attempt and provide feedback, please? I did something similar.

Comment: I don't know what is $n$. If it can grow as the partition gets finer, then that bound won't help.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I meant $k$, rather than n

Comment: Then, that's fine.

Comment: This is probably above the level of your course, but note this for later use - changing the values of a function on a countable set does not change the value of the (Lebesgue) integral.